# find php mysql and apache by terminal

Tags: php, macos, apache, terminal

I'm using my mac terminal for some webs on web-hosting
how can I know the php version and mysql version and apache version just by mac terminal for each web without using `phpinfo()`; in php file.

phpinfo show

```
php : PHP Version 5.6.40
mysql : mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev
Apache : _SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] : Apache
```

On terminal

```
php -v : 5.2.17
mysql --version : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.21, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
httpd -v : Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

the php code show a blank page without any text

```
<?php $version = apache_get_version(); echo "$version\n"; ?>
```

Comment: `php -v` for PHP, `mysqld --version` for mysql and `httpd -v` for apache

Comment: phpinfo give php version 5.6 but php -v give PHP 5.2.17

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php

Comment: @catcon so that mean I have to use phpinfo because it show the right version but on phpinfo I didn't found apache version it's show only apache without telling the version 
on _SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] says only apach but no version and for sqld --version i get `-bash: mysqld: command not found`

Comment: PHP has a built function to fetch apache version: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php

Comment: @catcon  : `<?php $version = apache_get_version(); echo "$version\n"; ?> ` it show only blank page without any text

Answer (score 0):

PHP: `php -v`

Apache: `httpd -v`

MySql: `mysqld --version`

Comment: php -v show wrong version of php on phpinfo show 5.6 but php -v show 5.2